# "Sum" field/option is not visible in "Running Total Fields" in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am using vs-2012, vb.net for desktop application. 
In crystal report I am trying to display total of column (group wise).
In report, grouping is done. But "sum" field/option is not visible in "Running Total Fields". ([image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v4HQ.png))
I am using first time "grouping" and "Running Total Fields" in crystal report. So I used a youtube video for a reference. Link- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzPRbOaHG_g
In video at 06:50 there are much more options are visible in list (including sum option), but in my list sum option is not visible and options are less.
Where am I doing wrong?

Actually, I am creating CR from an xml file, not from directly sql database. In below code, I am creating datatable from datagridview, then those values passed to xml file and then I set that xml file as data source of report.

code:

```
Dim ds_report As New DataSet()
Dim dt_report As New DataTable()
Dim cr As New CrystalReport1()
    
Private Sub Form7_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     set_cr_field()
     create_report()
End Sub
    
Private Sub set_cr_field()
     dt_report.Columns.Add("Total Com", GetType(String))
    
     For Each dgr As DataGridViewRow In dgv_report.Rows
        Dim total_com as string
        total_com = dgr.Cells(25).Value.ToString
        dt_report.Rows.Add(total_com)
     Next
     ds_report.Tables.Add(dt_report)
     ds_report.WriteXmlSchema("cr_swastik.xml")
End Sub
    
Private Sub create_report()
     cr.SetDataSource(ds_report)
     CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr
     CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like your field "Table1.Total Com" has a datatype that CR doesn't want to summarize, e.g. a string. You might want to check that first.

Comment: no sir, I have checked that before posting a question. data type is double, and I have posted my code. I  am creating a CR from xml file, could that be the reason?

Comment: yes sir, you are right. actually, datatype is double in database, but while working with xml file I declared and used it as a string. I found it while I was posting my code and reading your valuable answer, thanks a lot sir.